# Is there a way to figure out why my production mysql is so slow?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php file which parses a txt file and writes the data to a Mysql table. The xml file is quite big, with over 6 million lines. I did this on my home computer, and it took about six hours for the whole process. Now I'm trying to do the exact same thing on my beefed-up dedicated server (32GB ram), and 12 hours later, it barely got through 10% of the records.

I don't know if it's connected, but I also imported a large sql file through phpmyadmin several days ago, and I thought it took much longer than it should.

What could be the problem?

TIA!

Comment: Have you indexed your DB? I had this problem years ago and didn't know about indexing. Solved everything. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: On the other hand, when you have a lot of indices on that particular table and insert one row at a time, the time might be spent mainly with reindexing.

Comment: Try two things: delayed inserts and things like `insert into tables values (), (), (), (), ();`. I had a script that had to insert hundreds of thousands records and I needed it to run fast, that increased speed almost 10 times.

Comment: @SpaceBeers do you mean whether I have an index in that table? I do. Also, how would having an index in the table or not affect the insert?

Comment: @Ranty I'm willing to try anything, but the main thing that's bothering me is that there seems to be a specific problem here, evidenced by the fact that the exact same process ran much faster on my home computer.

Comment: @Phil There can be million of reasons. First thing I'd look into is mysql configuration. Afaik, some options can dramatically change the speed of things like the one you are doing.

Comment: Are you using simplexml or xmlreader or xmlpath or xmlquery or what to parse the xml

Comment: Regarding the indexes/foreign key constraints; it's possible to disable foreign key checks during the import and re-enable the afterwards. http://gauravsohoni.wordpress.com/2009/03/09/mysql-disable-foreign-key-checks-or-constraints/

Comment: I would advice to pre-process the XML and split the process to 'batches'. Having a single process run for so many hours will cause serious headaches if it is stopped half-way. Import in batches and register each batch that completed successfully. Be sure to run each batch inside a transaction.

Comment: @DoSparKot why thank you :-). But actually, this is a different file than the one you helped me with :-)

Comment: @thaJeztah you're right, and I'll probably do that in the future, but the problem here seems to be in my mysql setup.

Comment: I realized I made a mistake in the question; it's not an xml file, it's a txt file. Edited that. We're using $handle = fopen($myFile, 'r'); - while (!feof($handle)){$data = fgets($handle); to process the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up implementing all the changes to the DB settings as advised here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/

And now the db is roaring along! I'm not sure exactly which setting was the one that made the difference, but it's working now, so that the main thing! In any case all of you also gave me great advice which I'll be following up on, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unless you do profiling and stuff like EXPLAIN queries, it's hard to say.

There are some possibilities that may be worth investigating though:

- Lots of indexes: If you're doing INSERTS, then every index associated with the table you're INSERTING into will need to be updated.  If there's a lot of indexes, then a single insert can trigger a lot of writes.  You can solve this by dropping the indexes before you start and reinstating them afterward
- MyISAM versus InnoDB: The former tends to be faster as it sacrifices features for speed.  Writing to an InnoDB table tends to be slower. NOTE: I'm merely pointing out that this is a potential cause of an application running slower, I'm not recommending that you change an InnoDB table to MyISAM!
- No transaction: If using InnoDB, you can speed up bulk operations by doing them inside a transaction.  If you're not using a transaction, then there's an implicit transaction around every INSERT you do.
- Connection between the PHP machine and the SQL server: In testing you were probably running both PHP and the SQL server on the same box.  You may have been connecting through a named pipe or over a TCP/IP connection (which has more overhead), but in either case the bandwidth is effectively unlimited.  If the SQL server isn't the same machine as the one running the PHP script then it will be restricted to whatever bandwidth exists in the connection between the two.
- Concurrent users: You were the only user at any given time of your test SQL database.  The live system may and will have any number of additional users connected and running queries at a given time.  That's going to take time away from your script, adding to its run time.  You should run big SQL jobs at night so as not to inconvenience other users, but also so they can't take performance away from you too. 
  There are other reasons too, but the ones above are worth investigating first.

Of course the problem may be on the PHP side, you can't be sure that it's on the database until you investigate exactly where it's slowing down and why.

Comment: Only InnoDB supports foreign key constraints, so switching to another engine just for performance while importing is bad advice.

Comment: I didn't advise switching away from InnoDB, I think the extra features it offers are worth the performance loss.  I merely pointed out that in some cases InnoDB is slower.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was a bit too strong, just trying to point out the OP what the consequences could be when switching to a different engine

Comment: Could I import the data to an myisam table and then change the table over to innodb?

Comment: @Phil in theory yes, you could, provided there were no foreign key constraints.  However, I really would not recommend doing that because it's a bad habit to get into, and you could potentially break a database schema by doing that, especially on a live system that is depending on the foreign keys for data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

Check if php `memory_limit` setting or Mysql buffer settings is lower on server than local.

Comment: Mysql buffer settings are the same, php memory_limit is 100 bigger on server (I raised it to 12800M to try and improve performance).

Comment: Mysql side other options are available to check like slow query logs and show process list to check which query is most slow on server. If nothing like that then Something on php side like divide the task in batches may be useful (However i am skeptical if local's performance is faster then only optimizing php may not work.)